# Append data to table by ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm having issue with appending my data to table body.

## Code

```
$.ajax({
  type:'GET',
  url:'{{url('dashboard/customer-groups')}}/'+ordID,
  success:function(data){
    console.log(data);  //screenshot below
  }
});
```

## screenshot

data returned by ajax code above in 2 categories (group and customers)

[image: one]

## HTML

```
<table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th> // from customers array
        <th>Company</th> // from customers array
        <th>Province</th> // from customers array
        <th>City</th> // from customers array
        <th>Email</th> // from customers array
        <th>Industry</th> // from customers array
        <th>Group</th> // from group
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table_customer"></tbody>
</table>
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the response data and append them in the table body using `.each()` on *success*.

**Demo:**

```js
let  data = {customers: [
  {id: 1, name:'John', group_id: 111, industry_id: 'xyz', company: 'abc', province: 'aaa', city: 'vv', email: 'aa@gmail.com'},
  {id: 2, name:'Kate', group_id: 222, industry_id: 'lmn', company: 'abc2', province: 'bbb', city: 'qq', email: 'zz@gmail.com'}
]};

$(data.customers).each(function(_, i){
  var row = `<tr><td></td><td>${i.name}</td><td>${i.company}</td><td>${i.province}</td><td>${i.city}</td><td>${i.email}</td><td>${i.industry_id}</td><td>${i.group_id}</td></tr>`;
  $('#table_customer').append(row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th> 
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Province</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Email</th> 
        <th>Industry</th> 
        <th>Group</th> 
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table_customer"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you it does return data however i need fix some parts as it return as undefined. but that's not the issue. **the issue is i need to clear my table when i send another request**. `how to do that?`

Comment: @mafortis, you can clear the `tbody` with `$('#table_customer').html('');` as the first line in success:)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url:'{{url('dashboard/customer-groups')}}/'+ordID,
      success:function(data){
        const tr = $('tr');
        for (var key in data) {
           var obj = data[key];
           var id = "<td>"+obj.id+"</td>";
var group_id = "<td>"+obj.group_id+"</td>";


     // add more columns for other attributes
           var allTds = id+group_id;
         }
        tr.append(allTds);
       $('#data-table').append(tr);
      }
    });
```

Comment: return this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'group' of undefined
    at Object.success`